# Duplicate lines in region "in-place"

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am trying to code an elisp function which takes all (non-empty) lines in the current region and duplicates these lines *in-place*. I'll give you an example:

This input:

> Line1
>   Line2
>   Line3

Becomes

> Line1
>   Line1
>   Line2
>   Line2
>   Line3
>   Line3

If there were empty lines, they would remain in place and should not be duplicated. If have coded the following function:

```lisp
(defun duplicate-lines-in-region (beg end)
  "Duplicates the lines in the current region \"in-place\"."
  (interactive "r")
  (if (use-region-p)
      (let* ((text (buffer-substring-no-properties (region-beginning) (region-end)))
             (lines (split-string text "\n" t))
             (num-lines (length lines))
             (current-line 0)
             (end-pos 0))
        (save-excursion
          (goto-char (region-beginning))
          (while (< current-line num-lines)
            (end-of-line)
            (insert "\n")
            (insert (nth current-line lines))
            (next-line)
            (setq current-line (+ current-line 1))
            (setq end-pos (point))))
        (goto-char end-pos))
    (error "No active region!")))
```

However, this function has some (at least two) bugs:

1. Empty lines are not ignored but rather completely destroy the output (lines are inserted in the wrong places).
2. The first line that is inserted is always inserted with the wrong indentation (at column zero), all other lines are inserted at the right indentation.

I'm kinda stuck with advancing the function to a more useful state. Also, I highly doubt that my approach is particularly efficient/well-written... maybe some elisp-guru knows a more straightforward approach that can be used to work on each line in a region individually...

Answer (score 3):

This might be cheating, but you could just use a regex replace to match non-blank lines and replace them with the captured line and a duplicate. Use <kbd>M-x replace-regexp</kbd> with a region highlighted, and the following arguments:

- Replace regexp: `\(.+\)$`
- With: `\&^J\&`

Note, in the above, `^J` represents a newline/quoted enter key, <kbd>C-q C-j</kbd>.

To translate this into elisp, you just need to make sure to escape the backslashes and parentheses:

```
(defun duplicate-lines-in-region (beg end)
  (interactive "*r")
  (replace-regexp "\\(.+\\)$" "\\&\n\\&" nil beg end))
```